# suggested edit review: 1 reject + 1 approval = approval?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Here's a [suggested edit entry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5046772) from the review queue. I thought it took multiple approvals, and more approvals than rejects, for an edit suggestion to get approved, but this 
went through with one rejection and one approval?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That question was approved by the author of the original question, so it got automatically accepted.

[It's not said explicitly in the help page, but it does say:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

> The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.

This implies to me that if the author likes it, it's as if they had done the edit themselves.

Comment: +1, didn't think to check that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Short:

- Since @mahmood (The OP) reviewed it and approved it, the following reviews won't make any difference
- Only The OP and moderators can do this kind of votes to approve or reject without using "improve" or "reject and edit".

Comment: "Only The OP and moderators can do this kind of votes to approve or reject." ... well not really. Everyone with review rights have the ability the instantly approve or reject edits by using "improve" or "reject and edit".

Comment: @Tom Edited mine.