# RE: 1 reject + 1 approval = approval?

Tags: discussion, documentation

This particular question is about Documentation, but here's a similar one about Review Queues: [suggested edit review: 1 reject + 1 approval = approval?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260380/suggested-edit-review-1-reject-1-approval-approval)

The accepted answer of that question states:

> That question was approved by the author of the original question, so it got automatically accepted.

Fair enough. But that doesn't appear to be the case on Documentation.

Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/66196

This draft was rejected by one user with <2k reputation, then approved by another user with <2k reputation.

> [image]

The problem here though is that the user who approved the request has no previous edit history on that particular example.

So why was this request approved?